# Error con las clases de tailwind junto con variables de javascritpt

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind, vite

Tengo un componente de react que recibe por props una variable llamada color, dependiendo de esa variable le establece el color a una alerta de tailwind, el problema es que la variable color no funcoiona correctamente, debería ver la alerta así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero la veo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi componente se ve así:

```
const Mensaje = ({ mensaje:{titulo, msg, color} }) => {

  return (
    <div
      className={`mt-10 bg-${color}-100 border border-${color}-500 text-${color}-700 px-4 py-3 rounded relative`}
      role="alert">
      {
        titulo && <strong className="font-bold">{ titulo }: </strong>
      }
      <span className="block sm:inline">{ msg }</span>
      <span className="absolute top-0 bottom-0 right-0 px-4 py-3">
        <svg
          className={`fill-current h-6 w-6 text-${color}-500`}
          role="button"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          viewBox="0 0 20 20">
          <title>Close</title>
          <path d="M14.348 14.849a1.2 1.2 0 0 1-1.697 0L10 11.819l-2.651 3.029a1.2 1.2 0 1 1-1.697-1.697l2.758-3.15-2.759-3.152a1.2 1.2 0 1 1 1.697-1.697L10 8.183l2.651-3.031a1.2 1.2 0 1 1 1.697 1.697l-2.758 3.152 2.758 3.15a1.2 1.2 0 0 1 0 1.698z" />
        </svg>
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Mensaje;
```

Lo extraño es que si reemplazo las variables "**${color}**" por directamente "**red**" y luego la vuelvo a cambiar a "**${color}**" si funcionan correctamente pero solo con el color red y dejan de funcionar cuando recargo Vite. Me pasa lo mismo con otros colores, green, yellow... Si escribo el color directamente sin usar variables funciona y a partir de ahí puedo usar ese color en las variables las veces que quiera hasta que recargue Vite.

Además en el html final, el componente está bien definido pero no aplica el color correctamente.
Así es como se ve el resultado:

```
<div
  class="mt-10 bg-red-100 border border-red-500 text-red-700 px-4 py-3 rounded relative"
  role="alert">
  <span class="block sm:inline">Todos los campos son obligatorios</span>
  <span class="absolute top-0 bottom-0 right-0 px-4 py-3">
    <svg
      class="fill-current h-6 w-6 text-red-500"
      role="button"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      viewBox="0 0 20 20">
      <title>Close</title>
      <path d="M14.348 14.849a1.2 1.2 0 0 1-1.697 0L10 11.819l-2.651 3.029a1.2 1.2 0 1 1-1.697-1.697l2.758-3.15-2.759-3.152a1.2 1.2 0 1 1 1.697-1.697L10 8.183l2.651-3.031a1.2 1.2 0 1 1 1.697 1.697l-2.758 3.152 2.758 3.15a1.2 1.2 0 0 1 0 1.698z"></path>
    </svg>
  </span>
</div>
```

Mi proyecto en github:
https://github.com/Romera02rrs/PortafolioWeb/tree/master/frontend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segun la documentacion:

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

Si utiliza la interpolación de cadenas o concatena nombres de clases parciales, Tailwind no los encontrará y, por lo tanto, no generará el CSS correspondiente

envia la clase completa

ejemplo:

const colorBorder = 'border-red'

className={`${colorBorder}`}

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que el problema se deba a que la variable color no contiene el valor esperado. Puedes verificar el valor de color en el componente Mensaje agregando una línea de código para imprimir el valor en la consola, por ejemplo:

```
const Mensaje = ({ mensaje:{titulo, msg, color} }) => {
  console.log(color);

  return (
    // ...
  );
};
```

Luego, cuando el componente se renderice, puedes verificar el valor de color en la consola del navegador. Si el valor no es el esperado, puedes asegurarte de que el componente Mensaje está recibiendo el valor correcto de color como propiedad.

Si el valor de color en la consola es el esperado, entonces el problema podría ser que la clase de tailwind que estás utilizando en el componente Mensaje no existe o no se está aplicando correctamente. Puedes verificar las clases que estás utilizando y asegurarte de que sean válidas para tailwind.

Comment: Estos console.log() me devuelven lo siguiente: `console.log(color);   console.log(mt-10 bg-${color}-100 border border-${color}-500 text-${color}-700 px-4 py-3 rounded relative);` Resultado: `red, mt-10 bg-red-100 border border-red-500 text-red-700 px-4 py-3 rounded relative`. Es decir que funciona correctamente. Lo extraño es que si cambio las variables **${color}** por los colores correspondientes sin usar variables, poniendo directamente **red**, si funciona, luego vuelvo a cambiar de **red** a **${color}** y ya funciona bien hasta que recargue el proyecto en vite.